# Error of loading data from xml file in C# on dot net visual studio 2013 on win7

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I need to load data from xml file from C# in dot net visual studio 2013 on win7 .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <!--startup-->
   <MyApplication xmlns="http://myWeb.com/MyApplication.xsd">
  <myinformation my_id="587987" name="this is my name "/>
 </MyApplication >
 <!--/startup-->
</configuration>
```

My C# code:

```
 XNamespace ns = "http://myWeb.com/MyApplication.xsd";
 XElement node = doc.Root.Element(ns + "myinformation");
```

But, the node is "null".

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("xml.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://myWeb.com/MyApplication.xsd";
var element = xml.Root.Element(ns + "MyApplication").Element(ns + "myinformation");
```